# saveOrUpdate doesn't work in Spring Data with H2 database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, h2

I have for loop in my program where I save new objects to database. It looks like

```
for (String value: readvalue.readValue()) {
            Value value= getValueForSomething(something);
            System.out.println(value);
            valueRepository.save(value);
        }
```

And this fragment of code is executed every 30s and saving to database all values. Some values in database have two same fields and one other. How can I update values in h2 database instead of insert new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that within your for loop, create a method that checks to see if the object already exists in your H2 DB by querying for it using an unique identifier like an id. Use the following example RDB query as a reference:

```
    private static final String PRODUCT_ALREADY_EXISTS_QUERY = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1"
        + " FROM inventory.products "
        + " WHERE 1 = 1"
        + " AND id = :id)";
```

Then, if the record does exists, then call an update method that utilizes a query to UPDATE using the unique identifier. An RDB example query would be:

```
    private static final String UPDATE_QUERY = "UPDATE inventory.products"
        + " SET (company_id, name, price, type, quantity, created_date, last_modified_date) = "
        + " (:companyId, :productName, :price, :productType, :quantity, :createdDate, :lastModifiedDateTime)"
        + " WHERE id = :id ";
```

If the record doesn't exist, then just create the record like you are.